# where is the Qt designer app loaded on my system?

Tags: python, qt-designer

I loaded QtPy5 and QtPy5-tools successfully using pip on VSCode. But I cant for the life of me find it on my system.
Is it an .exe program?

where should I be looking please and what is it called

TIA

Comment: "successfully using pip on VSCode." Then it installs to the same place that `pip` installs everything else. It could be that there are multiple versions of Python on your system, in which case there can be multiple `pip`s; you will need to make sure of which one VS Code used (it will correspond to the Python that VS Code is using).

Answer (score 0):

you just hold ctrl key and move your cursor on the QtPy5 and then click it it should take you the the file location of the QtPy5. i think this should work.